# C# interactive window in Visual Studio 2015 CTP 6

Tags: c#, interactive, roslyn, visual-studio-2015

How I can get the C# interactive window? I have [Visual Studio 2015](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2015) CTP 6 installed.

And I installed [Roslyn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Compiler_Platform), according to [these instructions](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Getting-Started-on-Visual-Studio-2015-CTP-6).

According to blog post *[Using the C# Interactive Window that comes with Roslyn](http://www.filipekberg.se/2011/11/14/using-the-c-interactive-window-that-comes-with-roslyn/)*, now I should see C# interactive at

> *View* -> *Other Windows* -> *C# Interactive Window*

but it's absent.

Did I miss something?

Comment: You can build & install it from source.

Comment: install what? Roslyn?

Comment: http://source.roslyn.io/#Roslyn.VisualStudio.Interactive.Setup/VisualStudioSetupInteractive.csproj

Comment: okay, will look at it.

Comment: If you are OK with a standalone (i.e. non-Visual Studio) C# REPL, perhaps take a look at [CShell](http://cshell.net/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> **Update (Nov 2016):** It appears that the C# Interactive tool window has been reintroduced. I am using VS 2015 Update 3, which has it; but it has possibly been reintroduced with VS 2015 Update 1 already.

You missed the fact that the blog articles you link to were posted back in 2011, where VS 2015 was not even on the horizon yet. These articles applied to VS 2010 and (I assume) a very early version of Roslyn.

By the way, CTPs are preview versions of a product. As long as a Microsoft product is in the CTP stage, it is subject to the possibility of rapid and even short-term feature changes. So even if these articles did apply to VS 2015, they would have to be about the *exact* same version of the product that you are using; otherwise you would have no guarantee that they contained up-to-date information.

#### See also:

- [C# REPL feature request for VS 2015 on Microsoft's Visual Studio User Voice site](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2066219-c-repl-execute-one-off-c-code-on-the-fly-from)

  It appears the C# Interactive window worked for VS 2010 and VS 2012, but was no longer supported in some later versions of VS.

Comment: Do you mean that C# Interactive is not available in VS 2015? In your link, I thought they're asking about C# Interactive without Roslyn. In this article "Roslyn Compiler in Visual Studio 2015": http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/66489a/what-is-roslyn-compiler-in-visual-studio/ is written: "interactive use of the C# and VB languages".

Comment: Yes, from what I've read, I would guess that there won't be an inbuilt C# Interactive window in the final release of VS 2015. But like I said, CTPs are previews. VS 2015 is in the preview stage. Whether there will be a C# Interactive window or not cannot be said with certainty. The reply on User Voice suggests that it likely *won't* be included in the main product. Also, they are not asking for a C# REPL with or without Roslyn; they're simply asking for it. Someone also mentioned that Roslyn included a C# Interactive window at some time but that no longer seems to be the case.

Answer (score 10):

Now you can have C# interactive in VS 2015!! After waiting it for 3 years!
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/10/08/visual-studio-2015-update-1-ctp.aspx
Wish you happy interactive coding!

Comment: Yeah. Isn't that awesome?

Answer (score 5):

[Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 was released](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update1-vs.aspx#Csharp), so the Visual Studio interactive window is back for C#.

UPDATE:

[Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 has released](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update2-vs.aspx) recently.

Answer (score 1):

According to the talks at Microsoft Build Conference 2015, C# interactive won't be shipped with VS 2015 RTM - But the code is available on GitHub which you can pull, build and install it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible now.

In Visual Studio 2015, just go to *View*, *Other Windows*, *Interactive C#* and have fun.

Also, you can check the blog post *[Interactive C#](http://avillenas.com/post/interactive-c)*.

Answer (score -1):

It's available in Visual Studio 2015 update 2.